# Highcharts Heat map not displaying data yet correctly labelling

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts, heatmap

Having trouble with Highcharts heat map; trying to somewhat imitate the example large-heatmap with my own data in a slightly different format yet can't manage to get it to draw properly.

[Image snip of the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gEjDg.png)

Demo here:

https://jsfiddle.net/17jsrxfk/1/

```
 yAxis: {
  type: 'datetime',
  labels: {
    format: '{value:%H:%M}'
  },
  dateTimeLabelFormats: { // don't display the dummy year
    month: '%e. %b',
    year: '%b'
  }
```

As can be seen, the tooltip manages to find and respond to the correct data at that point, and even changes colour; along with the colour axis at the bottom responding correctly.

```
[1456444800000, 2700600000, 54.18855218855219], etc
```

The data is in milliseconds, the first value being the date of record (d,m,y) and the second value being a date (m,h,d,m,y) with a dummy Day Month Year of 0,0,1970; the third value being the actual reading.

I'm not sure if this is a problem with Highcharts somewhere, or if I've made a rookie mistake as i am fairly new to Highcharts. 
I haven't been able to find any reproductions of this problem elsewhere, and have spent a good few hours trying to find a solution.

Hints and Tips appreciated too!
Thanks

Comment: It looks like the problem is connected with the plugin you are loading on the beginning, without this plugin everything works fine, if you will set colsize and rowsize of your columns: https://jsfiddle.net/17jsrxfk/2/

Comment: Wow how about that, Thanks mate! I was following highcharts example with their large heatmap and just copied that plugin. 
Why would colsize and rowsize be required?

Comment: It is because you are not using categories (standard type of axis for heatmap). Your heatmap cells won't know how big they should be. That is the reason why you need to give them this info manually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> It looks like the problem is connected with the plugin you are loading on the beginning, without this plugin everything works fine, if you will set colsize and rowsize of your columns: jsfiddle.net/17jsrxfk/2 – Grzegorz Blachliński

Thanks to this guy for solving my problem!